# Google Accounts: Reverse lookup of recovery-email

Tags: google

Is there a way to check all the emails that has my email as "Recovery Email"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to actively query this. The most effective method is looking through your past e-mails, since you were alerted at the time your account was set as a recovery e-mail.

I found such e-mail with the following title:

> Someone added you as their recovery email

The content of the e-mail will look something like this:

> Someone added yourmail@gmail.com as their recovery email
>
> othermail@gmail.com wants your email address to be their recovery email.
>
> If you don’t recognize this account, it’s likely your email address was added in error. You can remove your email address from that account.
>
> Disconnect email

The e-mail includes a link to disconnect your mail address as a recovery address.